# How To Make "Color-Option" On A Product-Card To Be Clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just created few product cards for my website. Each product card consist of cart icon, image, description, stars, color-option and price. my first product card work well where each color-option is clicked, the picture able to change automatically. However, the problem occur where it does not work on other product card. I check all the codes but i cant find any error. Please help me!!!

Below is the code. Thank you in advance for your help.

APOLOGIES AS I HAVE TO REMOVE SOME OF CODES DUE TO LIMITED WORDS.!!!!!

You may view the full code in here: https://jsfiddle.net/xzyjkauo/

```js
<!-- -------------------------------START OF JAVASCRIPT FOR INDEX.PHP--------------------- -->
    <script> 
      var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";  
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }    

        let circle = document.querySelector(".color-option");

      circle.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
          let target = e.target;
          if(target.classList.contains("circle")){
          circle.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
          target.classList.add("active");
          document.querySelector(".main-images .active").classList.remove("active");
          document.querySelector(`.main-images .${target.id}`).classList.add("active");
          }
      });
    </script>
    <!-- -------------------------------END OF JAVASCRIPT FOR INDEX.PHP--------------------- -->
```

```css
<style>
   
   /*----------------------START OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/
      body {
        background: #c8e8e9;  
        /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff9472, #f2709c); */ 
        /*background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9472, #f2709c); */
        background-color: #D1E8E2;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        top: 0px;
        
        grid-gap: 20px;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      article {
          width: 90%;
          max-width: 600px;
          padding: 20px;
          margin: 0px auto;
      }
      /*----------------------END OF CSS PAGE BACKGROUND-----------------*/

      /*----------------------START OF SIGNUP AND LOGIN BUTTON -----------------*/
      .button {
        background-color: #D9B08C;
        border: 0;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 22px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 2px 2px;
        margin-top: 0;
        float: right;
        opacity: 0.9;
        transition: 0.3s;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
      }

      .button:hover {opacity: 1}
      /*----------------------END OF SIGNUP AND LOGIN BUTTON -----------------*/

      /*----------------------START OF CSS NAVBAR -----------------*/
      
      /*.img{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 4px;
      }*/

      .nav {
        overflow: hidden; 
        background-color: #116466;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }

      .nav i {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .nav a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .nav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }

      .nav a.active {
        background-color: #38444d;
        color: white;
      }

      .nav ul {
        list-style:none;
      }
      .nav ul li{
        display:inline-block; 
        padding:0 9px; 
        position:relative;
      }
      .nav ul li:not(:last-child)::after{
        content:""; 
        border:2px solid #e2e2e2;
        border-width: 2px 1px 0 0;
        position:absolute; 
        right:-3px; 
        top:0; 
        height:200%;
      }
      /*----------------------END OF CSS NAVBAR-----------------*/

      /*----------------------START OF CSS LOGO AND SEARCH BUTTON-----------------*/     

      .section1 .logo a{
        padding: 60px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 60px;
        font-size: 55px;
        font-family: Lucida Handwriting;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 600;
        z-index: 6;
      }
      .section1 .logo a{
        color: #fff;
      }

      .section1 .img{
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 120px;
        
      }

      .section1 .box{
        max-width: 700px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 600px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
        padding-top: 70px;

      }
      .section1 .box .search-box{
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        max-width: 550px;
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 25px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }

      .section1 .search-box input{
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #fff;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
      font-size: 18px;
      }
      .section1 .search-box .icon{
        position: absolute;
        right: -2px;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
        background: #FFF;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: #2C3531;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
      }

      /*----------------------END OF CSS LOGO AND SEARCH BUTTON-----------------*/ 

      
      /*----------------------------------------END OF CSS PRODUCT CARD----------------------------*/
      .product-card {
              position: relative;
              max-width: 355px;
              width: 100%;
              border-radius: 25px;
              padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
              margin-bottom: 50px;
              background: #fff;
              box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              z-index: 3;
              /*overflow: hidden;*/
          }
          .product-card .logo-cart{
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: space-between;
          }
          .product-card .logo-cart img{
              height: 60px;
              width: 60px;
              object-fit: cover;
          }
          .product-card .logo-cart i{
              font-size: 27px;
              color: #707070;
              cursor: pointer;
              transition: color 0.3s ease;
          }
          .product-card .logo-cart i:hover{
              color: #333;
          }
          .product-card .main-images{
              position: relative;
              margin-top: 30px;
              margin-left: 30px;
              height: 210px;
          }
          .product-card .main-images img{
              position: absolute;
              height: 300px;
              width: 300px;
              object-fit: cover;
              /* transform: rotate(18deg);*/
              left: 12px;
              top: -40px;
              z-index: -1;
              opacity: 0;
              transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
          }
          .product-card .main-images img.active{
              opacity: 1;
          }
          .product-card .product-details .product_name{
              font-size: 24px;
              font-weight: 500;
              color: #161616;
          }
          .product-card .product-details p{
              font-size: 12px;
              font-weight: 400;
              color: #333;
              text-align: justify;
          }
          .product-card .product-details .stars i{
              margin: 0 -1px;
              color: #333;
          }
          .product-card .color-price .color-option{
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
          }
          .color-price{
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-between;
              align-items: center;
              margin-top: 10px;
          }
          .color-price .color-option .color{
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: 500;
              color: #333;
              margin-right: 8px;
          }
          .color-option  .circles{
              display: flex;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle{
              height: 18px;
              width: 18px;
              background: #0071C7;
              border-radius: 50%;
              margin: 0 4px;
              cursor: pointer;
              transition: all 0.4s ease;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.blue.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #0071C7;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.pink{
              background: #FA1795;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.pink.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #FA1795;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.yellow{
              background: #F5DA00;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.yellow.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #F5DA00;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.red{
              background: #ff0000;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.red.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #ff0000;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.purple{
              background: #5d008a;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.purple.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #5d008a;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.green{
              background: #007700;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.green.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #007700;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.gold{
              background: #c78700;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.gold.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #c78700;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.white{
              background: #f8f8f8;
          }
          .color-option  .circles .circle.white.active{
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
                          0 0 0 4px #f8f8f8;
          }
          .color-price .price{
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
          }
          .color-price .price .price_num{
              font-size: 25px;
              font-weight: 600;
              color: #707070;
          }
          .color-price .price .price_letter{
              font-size: 10px;
              font-weight: 600;
              margin-top: -4px;
              color: #707070;
          }
          .product-card .button1{
              position: relative;
              height: 50px;
              width: 100%;
              border-radius: 25px;
              margin-top: 30px;
              overflow: hidden;
              padding: 0px 0px;
          }
          .product-card .button1 .button-layer{
              position: absolute;
              height: 100%;
              width: 300%;
              left: -100%;
              background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,#ff9900, #006699,#ff9900, #006699 );
              transition: all 0.4s ease;
              border-radius: 25PX;
          }
          .product-card .button1:hover .button-layer{
              left: 0;
          }
          .product-card .button1 button{
              position: relative;
              height: 100%;
              width: 100%;
              background: none;
              outline: none;
              border: none;
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: 600;
              letter-spacing: 1px;
              color: #fff;
          }
          .parent {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-gap: 20px;
          }

          @media screen and (min-width: 992px){
            .product-card-items{
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            }
            .product-card-col-r-bottom{
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            }
          }   
          @media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
              .product-card-items{
                  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
              }
              .product-card {
                  margin-right: 1rem;
                  margin-left: 1rem;
              }
              .product-card  .text-light{
                  width: 50%;
              }
          }

          @media screen and (min-width: 1336px){
              .product-card-items{
                  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
              }
              .product-card-collection-wrapper{
                  display: grid;
                  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
              }
              .flex{
                  height: 60vh;
              }
              .product-card-col-left{
                  height: 121.5vh;
              }
          }

      /*----------------------------------------END OF CSS PRODUCT CARD----------------------------*/


      /*----------------------------------------START OF CSS SECTION CONTAINER----------------------------*/
      
      section#container1 {
        padding-top:100px;
        padding-left:100px;
        margin:0px;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        background: #FFCB9A;
        /*background: rgb(123,134,232);*/
        /*background: linear-gradient(164deg, rgba(123,134,232,1) 0%, rgba(246,140,255,1) 52%, rgba(255,222,50,1) 100%);*/
        color: #2C3531;
        min-height: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
      }

      section#container2 {
        background: #D1E8E2;
        /*background: rgb(123,211,232);*/
        /*background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(123,211,232,1) 0%, rgba(123,211,232,1) 0%, rgba(50,171,255,1) 100%);*/
        color: #0f2852;
        padding: 64px;
        
      }

      section#container3 {
        background: #D1E8E2;  
        /*background: rgb(123,211,232);*/
        /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #66ff99 100%);*/
        color: #0f2852;
        padding: 30px;
      }

      h2 {
        color: #2C3531;
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #686868;
      }

      h3 {
        color: #2C3531;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #686868;
      }

      /* Float the columns  */
      .column {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 0px;
        z-index: 5;
      }

      /* Style the counter cards */
      .card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        padding: 0 600px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }

      
   </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.php">
    <link rel="import" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/software_project/slider/index.html">  
    </head>

  <!-- -------------------------------------START OF HTML ------------------------------- -->
  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <button class="button   fa fa-sign-in" onclick="document.location='signup1.php'"> Sign-In</button>
      <button class="button   fa fa-user-circle" onclick="document.location='login1.php'"> Log-In</button>
            
      <ul>
        <li><i class=" fa fa-envelope"> hello.colorlib@gmail.com</i></li>
        
        <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section1">
      <!-- <div class="logo"><a>Let's Buy.</a></div>   -->
      <img src="Picture2.png" class="img" alt="logo" style="float:left; width:370px; height:160px;">    
        <div class="box">
          <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type here...">
            <label for="check" class="icon">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
      </div>
        
    </div


    <section id="container1">
        <!--  <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <h2>Card 1</h2>
            <br>    
          </div>
        </div>-->

      <div class="header">
          <h2>Our Products </h2>
          <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
      </div>

      <br>
      <br>

      <div class = "parent">
        <!-- ------------PRODUCT 1 ----------------- -->              
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
              <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
              <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
              <img id="blue" class="blue active" src="images/shirt1.jpg" alt="blue">
              <img id="red" class="red" src="images/shirt2.jpg" alt="red">
              <img id="purple" class="purple" src="images/shirt3.jpg" alt="purple">
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="product-details">
              <span class="product_name">Men Long Sleeve Shirt</span>
              <p>Elegant design: Simple and smart looking</p>
              <p>Slim fit cutting: Design to enhance your body ratio</p>
              <p>Breathable material: Best fabric to wear in hot weather</p>
              <div class="stars">
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
              <div class="color-option">
                  <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                  <div class="circles">
                  <span class="circle blue active"  id="blue"></span>
                  <span class="circle red " id="red"></span>
                  <span class="circle purple " id="purple"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">RM 49.90</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Forty-nine ringgit only</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="button1">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ------------PRODUCT 2 ----------------- --> 
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
              <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
              <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
              <img id="red" class="red active" src="images/nike1.png" alt="red">
              <img id="green" class="green" src="images/nike2.png" alt="green">
              <img id="white" class="white" src="images/nike3.png" alt="white">
              <img id="gold" class="gold" src="images/nike4.png" alt="gold">
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="product-details">
              <span class="product_name">Nike Air Max Sport Shoes</span>
              <p>Best shoe for sports training, casual walk, exercising  and many more !!!</p>
              <p>Light Weight, Comfort, Extra Grip <p>
              <div class="stars">
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
              <div class="color-option">
                  <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                  <div class="circles">
                  <span class="circle red active"  id="red"></span>
                  <span class="circle green " id="green"></span>
                  <span class="circle white " id="white"></span>
                  <span class="circle gold " id="gold"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="button1">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ------------PRODUCT 3 ----------------- --> 
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="logo-cart">
              <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">-->
              <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="main-images">
              <img id="purple" class="purple active" src="images/watch1.png" alt="purple">
              <img id="blue" class="blue" src="images/watch2.png" alt="blue">
              <img id="red" class="red" src="images/watch3.png" alt="red">
              <img id="green" class="green" src="images/watch4.png" alt="green">
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="product-details">
              <span class="product_name">Sppors Digital Sport Watch</span>
              <p>Unisex, high quality, authentic digital sport watch!</p>
              <div class="stars">
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bxs-star' ></i>
                  <i class='bx bx-star' ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-price">
              <div class="color-option">
                  <span class="color">Colour:</span>
                  <div class="circles">
                  <span class="circle purple active"  id="purple"></span>
                  <span class="circle blue " id="blue"></span>
                  <span class="circle red " id="red"></span>
                  <span class="circle green " id="green"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_num">$09.00</span>
                <span class="price_letter">Nine dollar only</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="button1">
            <div class="button-layer"></div>
            <button>Add To Cart</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>



    
    
  
     </body>
  <!-- -------------------------------------END OF HTML ------------------------------- -->
</html>
```

Comment: You should always use unique ID's. Ex.: `id="red"` is used 3 times.

Comment: @scrummy, may i know where do you refer it at in the code?

Comment: `<span class="circle red " id="red"></span>`  Some 'cirlces' has the same id

Comment: @scrummy, thank you for the tips. i have adjusted the code but still there is no changes on it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why only the frist product card was able to work, it's because you only selected the first item that has the `.color-option` class

```js
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".color-option");     
for (let i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
  circle[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
      var target = e.target; var targetid = target.id;
      if(target.classList.contains("circle")){
      circle[i].querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
      target.classList.add("active");
      document.querySelector(".main-images .active").classList.remove("active");
      document.querySelector(".main-images #"+targetid).classList.add("active");
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh MYYYYYYY!!!!!!!!. Your are my survivor. it works perfectly fine now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just a another confirmation. when i press on another color-option for instance, the  "red" color. the color option of red in other product-card also change. what shall i do to stop other product-card to not change?